# Why does Tanac"h specifically describe these males as "beautiul"?

Tags: tanach, yosef, king-david, king-saul, beauty

A "trivia" question I gave my son, yesterday, is - name three males described in Tanac"h as "beautiful" / good-looking:

The 3 I thought of  are:

- [Joseph](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9597&st=&pgnum=508&hilite=)
- Saul (See [Rada"k commentary on I Samuel 9:2](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9597&st=&pgnum=508&hilite=))
- David (See [Rada"k commentary on I Samuel 16:12](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14258&st=&pgnum=133))

(There may be other males, but I can't think of them, so feel free to edit, if needed.)

What is special about these 3 people that Tana"ch felt the specific need to describe how beautiful they were? Is there something, in particular, perhaps some hidden or important message as to why we need to know this information? What made these 3 people esp. "beautiful" more than other male personalities throughout Tana"ch that are not described this way?

Comment: Why do you ask specifically about males?

Comment: @Daniel mainly b/c of frequency. We tend to see women's features described more often in Tanac"h. Otherwise, no particular reason. Also, the above 3, in particular, were all "kings". (Yosef was considered like a king.) I wonder if that has anything to do with the need for that description.

Comment: - Avshalom ([Shmuel II 14:25](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15874#showrashi=true&v=25))
- Adoniyahu ([Melachim I 1:6](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15885#showrashi=true&v=6))

Comment: @Menachem Thanks. I forgot about these two. I won't yet edit the question, as I'm debating how I can improve it, or if I should delete it, altogether.

Comment: Joseph was pursued by [Potiphar's wife](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potiphar_and_his_wife) for rather obvious reasons, and Saul was chosen king based on his personal charisma and physical attributes.